# ModuleNotFoundError: No Module Named '...' [Python]

Tags: python, module

I have only written stand alone script before in Python. Now I am trying to write an app which can transform and migrate data between two databases. But when I am trying to create the different modules, they can not "find" each other.

This is what my workspace looks like right now.

```
  Project
     -PQF
         -db
             -__init__.py
             - DataSource.py
             - RecordSet.py
          -main
             -main.py
             - __init__.py
        - __init__.py
```

As I understod it, I need to create these "init.py" files in each module to make it understand that these are modules, these are currently empty.

What I am trying to do in the main file is to just import the different modules.

```py
       from PQF.db import DataSource as database
       from PQF.db import RecordSet

       def main():
         print("hello")
```

But I get the error:
      `ModuleNotFoundError: No Module named "PQF"`

What is it that I am doing wrong? Thank you for any help.

Comment: Have you set the python path to be your base PQF folder?

Comment: No I have not set any python path, do you have to permanently add it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the full code including the `__init__.py`

File - `db/__init__.py`

```py
from .DataSource import *
from .RecordSet import *
```

File - `main/__init__.py`

```py
from .main import *
```

File - `PQF/__init__.py`

```py
from .db import *
from .main import *
```

```py
from db import DataSource as database
from db import RecordSet

def main():
   print("hello")
```

Run the `main.py` script as `python3 -m main.main`

Comment: Maybe it has to do with the fact that my "__init__.py" files are just empty?

Comment: I have updated the answer. I have tested it on my machine.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is put `main.py` hand over your other scripts.

```
Project
     - PQF
        - db
            - __init__.py
            - DataSource.py
            - RecordSet.py
        - main.py
        - __init__.py
```

In your `main.py`, you now make your imports