# import modules from sibling folder

Tags: python, import

I have a python project in a repository that needs to import some classes from other repositories.
Since they are different repositories they need to stay at the same directory level.

A folder structure like:

```
repos
    |- my_project 
         |- main.py
    |- foo_folder
         |- foo.py
    |- bar_folder
         |- bar.py
```

In `myproject/main.py` I need to import the class `Foo_Class` from `foo_folder/foo.py` and `Bar_Class` from `bar_folder/bar.py`.

One way of doing so is:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '../foo_folder')
sys.path.insert(0, '../bar_folder')
```

then I can do

```
from foo_folder.foo import Foo_Class
from bar_folder.bar import Bar_Class
```

But I'm not a particular fan of this solution and also it's not PEP8 compilant:

```
PEP8: module level import not at top of file
```

---

I could also create inside my_project a shortcut to foo and a shortcut to bar, so the system will see those modules as subfolders.

However this again looks like a hack, I'll have to add this shortcuts to `.gitignore` and in Windows it doesn't work at all!

I don't know why but if I physically copy foo folder and name it `copy_of_foo_folder` I can then import it, but if I made a shortcut to foo I cannot import.

```
 |- my_project 
             |- shortcut_to_foo_folder
             |- copy_of_foo_folder
             |- main.py

from copy_of_foo_folder.foo import Foo   # WORKS
from shortcut_to_foo_folder.foo import Foo   # FAILS

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'shortcut_to_foo_folder'
```

---

So my question is. What is the standard way of importing modules that are not in a subfolder but at the same hierarchy level?

Answer (score 0):

You have to include `__init__.py` in every directory.

```
repos
    |- my_project 
         |- main.py
         |- __init__.py
    |- foo_folder
         |- foo.py
         |- __init__.py
    |- bar_folder
         |- bar.py
         |- __init__.py
    __init__.py
```

Please have a look at my Previous answer on what to include in `__init__.py`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56732285/7994074

Comment: Foo_folder is not inside my project directory. Even if I put `__init__.py` I won't be able to import it since it's in a sibling folder to my project.

Comment: In your example you run the project from a parent level (repos in my case) and you call the main program using `python -m main.main`. It will work but still looks like a hack, since you are basically setting your folder one level higher. But it's a solution to the problem

Comment: I think this is not a hack, this is how modules are called when they are required to execute. Here is the link - https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/modules.html#packages

Comment: but repos is not a packages folder. Is a folder that contain different projects. And one project might need libraries from another folder. But considering the whole repos folder a package is not what I want. Anyway thank for the suggestion