# Trying to create a python package - module can't be found

Tags: python, class, package

I am trying to create a package. Let's call it Blep.

I have made a folder, and moved the folder into the anaconda envoriment.

I have 2 files in the Blep folder:

```
Blep
   __init__.py
   cake.py
```

In **init**.py  I have:

```
from cake import *
```

In cake.py I have:

```
class scene:
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        pass
```

When I run a python file oly containing this line:

```
from Blep import *
```

I get:

```
line 1, in <module>
    from cake import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cake'
```

I've tripple checked with a tutorial and I think everything seems to be allright. But it does not work.

Would love your input

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please make the change in `__init__.py`

Instead of

```py
from cake import *
```

Do this

```py
from .cake import *
```

You can check my previous answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/56732285/7994074

Comment: Fixed my problem! Thank you

Comment: @PernkDernets: Don't forget to accept Parth's answer if it fixed your issue!

Comment: I forogt! Thank you @morris

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your program is searching for Module on your default directory

Try this :

In your program, use `sys.path.append('/path/to/search')` to add the names of directories you want Python to search for imported modules. `sys.path` is just the list of directories Python searches every time it gets asked to import a module, and you can alter it as needed (although I wouldn't recommend removing any of the standard directories!). Any directories you put in the environment variable `PYTHONPATH`will be inserted into `sys.path` when Python starts up.

Comment: I am in the defualt directory i think. also python finds the file _init__.py